# BimlExpress and VS2019 issues

Tags: visual-studio-2019, biml

Anyone successfully using BimlExpress and Visual Studio 2019 ?

The latest version of BimlExpress currently available is version 5.0.64108.0 aka 2019 R1, but it is in any way incompatible with Vs2019 version 16.9+

I'm writing this in hope that someone have found a workaround, or have a version where iit still working.

Update:
Trying to open a biml file freezes up Visual Studio entirely.

Comment: [According to the Varigence website the current version is **2020** R1 which includes VS 2019 support in the release notes](https://docs.varigence.com/bimlexpress/release-notes/BimlExpress-2020.1).  Are you sure you are on the latest version?

Comment: [According to the BimlExpress 2020 R1 Features and Highlights](https://docs.varigence.com/bimlexpress/release-notes/biml-express-2020-features#bimlexpress-2020-r1-release-notes) the link is still missing.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Varigence still not released any updated version after 2019 R1. No update I can find on their website  either. It's still buggy with VS2019.. unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

The extension BimlExpress only works with SQL Server Integration Services Projects 3.x. Newer Versions are not compatible. Did you check this? If necessary downgrade.

Comment: Yes, I've been on SQL Server Integration Services Projects v4.0, and downgraded again. Any leftover BIML functionality was 100% gone on v4.0.

Due You have a fully functionally BIML code editor window in Visual Studio, where You can see the the generated BIML xml ?

That version of the extention BimlExpress and VisualStudio are You using ?

My current versions are as follows:
VS2019 v.16.11.15
BimlExpress  1.0 aka v.5.0.64108.0 aka 2019 R1 
SQL Server Analysis Services  15.0.19623.0
SQL Server Data Tools  16.0.62205.05200
SQL Server Integration Services  15.0.2000.180  aka v.3.16

Comment: Do you mind explaning how to downgrade? I'm only aware of how to set the SQL Server version of a project, but not how to change the version of SSIS

Answer (score 1):

"Downgrade" Version of Integration Services can be downloded directly from [marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SSIS.SqlServerIntegrationServicesProjects)

Use Version 3.16 (latest GA Version).

worked for me :-)

Comment: Does the interactive biml code editor work as a two part window ?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't described any symptoms but I had a couple of bumps getting BIMLexpress to show up in VS2019.

First I had to go to extensions on the menu and check that it showed up. it did but right clicking on the SSIS Packages node didn't show anything. I clicked Toggle BIDS helper menus.

I restarted VS2019 and there is a yellow bar under the menu warning about extensions using deprecated API's. I enabled deprecated API usage and restarted then BIMLexpress displayed more entries in the extensions menu. Still no right click. Haven't road tested it yet other than adding a new BIML file.

The yellow bar may have been there all along and I just didn't notice it so the toggle BIDS helper step might be unnecessary.

Comment: Trying to open a biml file freezes up Visual Studio entirely.

Are You one of the few lucky ones, that got Your hands on the 2020 R1 releace before it was removes again by Varigance ?

Comment: It actually appears greyed-out in the Extensions menu even though it's installed. I've enabled the APIs from the yellow bar, but nothing. `Toggle BIDS Helper Menus` does nothing.